# How to check event handler assigned or not in QuickWatch

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I need to know that how to check any event handler already assigned ? (in QuickWatch)

Comment: Are you asking how to check if any event handler is attached to an event?

Comment: yes is correct  , but i need check in quickwatch.

Comment: This is not in general possible without knowing how the add and remove accessors are implemented.  Next to impossible in Winforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but I will give it a shot:

1. How to check if any event handlers attached to an event `TestEvent`:

   `TestEvent` will be null if no event handlers attached.
2. If one handler attached (single-cast delegate) `_invocationList == 0`:

   Paste the following to the QuickWatch expression string:

   ```
   ((System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo)(((System.Delegate)(TestEvent))._methodBase)).Name
   ```

   to find out what event handler is attached.
3. If more than one handler attached (multicast delegate) `_invocationList > 0`:

   You need to look through `_invocationList`, for example to check first attached method:

   ```
   ((System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo)(((System.Delegate)(((object[])(((System.MulticastDelegate)(TestEvent))._invocationList))[0]))._methodBase)).Name
   ```

   To check other attached handlers: change index to 1, 2, etc or just expand each element of the `_invocationList` array.

Alternatively to using `Name` property which is just a handler method name, you can use `m_toString` field which is method signature.

In all the examples about replace `TestEvent` with the name of your event.

**[Edit]** Didn't realize you are using WPF. WPF event system is much more complicated.

Let's say you have a button and what to check if any handler is attached to `MouseLeftButtonDown` event:

1. Open QuickWhatch.
2. Paste you button variable name (let's say `button1`).
3. Drill down through the bases classes till you got to the `UIElement`. Or to get there quickly paste this `((System.Windows.UIElement)(button1)).EventHandlersStore` to the expression input.
4. Locate and expand property `EventHandlersStore`.
5. Expand `_entries`.
6. Expand `_mapStore`.
7. Expand `[MS.Utility....]`
8. You will see the list of `_entry0`, `_entry1`, ... `_entry_n`. Each of those are all the events that the button has handlers assigned too.
9. To find out what handlers are assigned to, drill further to particular entry `Value` => `_listStore`.
10. You will see the list of `_entry0`, `_entry1` ... again. Those are all the handlers attached to this particular event.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting.How to show all event handlers some object in quickwatch ? for example i need show MouseLeftButtonDown or MouseMove , ... is null or no.

Comment: Thanks a lot , Do you suggest for SilverLight ?