# Cannot see event implementing interface in Visual Studio debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, interface

I have the following C# class:

```
public class SignInViewModel : ISwitchable
{
    IChildViewModelFactory _factory;
        
    // Implement ISwitchable interface.
    public event EventHandler<object> SwitchEvent;

    public SignInViewModel(IChildViewModelFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }
    ...
}
```

When I inspect `value` in the Visual Studio 2019 debugger, I cannot see the `SwitchEvent` field as a member:

```
((ISwitchable)value).SwitchEvent += ChildViewModel_SwitchEvent; // value is SignInViewModel instance.
```

I tried the following, but got the same result:

```
ISwitchable temp = (ISwitchable)value;
temp.SwitchEvent += ChildViewModel_SwitchEvent;
```

`temp` only shows the `_factory` and `SignInViewModel()` ctor as class members.

How can I see `SwitchEvent`, the event implementating the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SwitchEvent` is not a field. It is an event and has no value but assigned handler method

What you need to do is to invoke your event like this

```cs
if (SwitchEvent != null)
    (SwitchEvent(this));  // 'this' is a sender
```

Check this out - [how to view event handler assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6339381/1704458)

Comment: Thank you.  When I try what you suggest, I get: `error CS0079: The event 'ISwitchable.SwitchEvent' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=`
However, that's OK, what's more important is your setting me straight about it being an event, not a field, as well as that very useful link.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Sabuncu Interesting... My code had missing closing parentheses ")". It should work. Another way is - `SwitchEvent?.Invoke(....)`